# Как создать Vue js SPA?

Tags: php, vue.js, npm, spa, vue-cli

Зачем и когда нужен **npm** ?

Будет ли он работать на сервер или он не должен вообще работать на сервере ?

Какие шаги необходимо проделать чтобы создать одностраничное приложение используя **Vue js** на frontend и **PHP** на backend?

Допустим есть сайт. Серверная часть на **PHP**. Нужно сделать SPA используя Vue CLI. Можно ли использовать **npm**? Если да то КАК это сделать и будет ли оно работать на сайте ? Хостинг не поддерживает **Node.js**

*P.s: Знаю много вопросов. НО мне нужно чтобы кто то расставил все по полочкам.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай начнем с того что у vue есть достаточно исчерпывающая документация [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html).
На счет npm (npm как и yarn) это менеджер пакетов как composer для php, через него ты можешь установить нужные тебе плагины и тд.
Я так понимаю что ты хочешь использовать Vue + Laravel, если так то начиная с версии Laravel 6, работа с vue идет из коробки. Если я не прав то можно спокойно запустить бэк на субдомене (api.test.com), а фронт как test.com (с Laravel такой вариант тоже работает).
С помощью axios стучаться по апи для получения или отправки данных.
Что бы с помощью Vue Cli создать проект хватит простой команды `vue init webpack-simple <имя проекта>`. [Тут](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui) описано более подробно.
После выполнения простых шагов по типу указания имени проекта, автора и тд, (выбирается в консоли после ввода команды "vue init webpack-simple <имя проекта>"), вам нужно перейти в директорию с проектом выполнить npm install && npm run dev и все можете начинать работать с фронтом.

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем и когда нужен npm ?

Это - пакетный менеджер: установка / удаление пакетов. Также с помощью него часто запускают процесс сборки проекта, для этого в package.json есть секция `scripts`.

Нужен практически всегда для современных JS-приложений. Работает на NodeJS и ставится с ним (по крайней мере так в Ubuntu, Debian и CentOS).

> Будет ли он работать на сервер или он не должен вообще работать на сервере ?

На шаред-хостинге - скорее всего нет, если явно не заявили об этом, или это не спец хостинг. Большинство хостингов построены на LAMP, а значит там PHP.

Можно сделать так: поставить NodeJS + npm на свою машину, вести на ней разработку (`vue serve`), а затем собрать проект (`vue build`) и выложить готовый JS на сервер. Серверу лишь нужно будет отдавать готовый JS для браузера. А на беке как вы сами сообщили, будет работать PHP.

> Какие шаги необходимо проделать чтобы создать одностраничное приложение используя Vue js на frontend и PHP на backend?

1. Ознакомиться с [документацией Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/installation.html), пройти уроки
2. Сделать пробное приложение без работы с серверной частью
3. Добавить взаимодействие с сервером

> Допустим есть сайт. Серверная часть на PHP. Нужно сделать SPA используя Vue CLI.

Vue CLI - это надстройка над npm, по сути - пакет npm на глобальном уровне. Можно сделать VueJS приложение без Vue CLI, используя только npm. Для этого нужно ознакомиться с работой npm, и желательно, webpack - это такой "сборщик".

Вот я скопировал и подсократил пример из Laravel (для других фреймворков все полностью аналогично):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ...",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ..."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
    }
}
```

Разберем как это работает.

Если выполнить `npm run dev`, то запустится `npm run development`. А в нем указана переменная окружения для разработки `NODE_ENV=development` и запуск вебпака `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`. Веб-пак работает для новичка сложно, и я рекомендую использовать уже настроенное окружение, от того же Laravel.

В этом режиме произойдет сборка проекта для разработки, например можно отлаживать через [Vue.js devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd).

При запуске `npm run watch` будет аналогичная сборка, но npm еще и будет висеть и наблюдать за изменениями в файлах проекта, делая пересборку проекта на лету. Крайне рекомендую этот режим.

Перед выкладкой на сервер, сделайте `npm run prod`, на выходе получите JS (+CSS) файлы, которые готовы к размещению на сервере.

> Можно ли использовать npm? Если да то КАК это сделать и будет ли оно работать на сайте ? Хостинг не поддерживает Node.js

Ответил выше